# UITableViewCell like mail on iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitableview

How can I adjust a UITableViewCell so that it would show two fields after swiping it left - identical to how the mail client does it?
Right now I only see the "Delete" button. 
I would like to have the "More" field included there, too...

Also, for the first if clause Cell I do not get a "Insert" field.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.row == self.reports.count){
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to combine the fields with the | operator or something? 
Thanks, EL-

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Add more button to UITableViewCell When scrolling it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847473/how-to-add-more-button-to-uitableviewcell-when-scrolling-it)

Comment: This isn't a standard feature of `UITableViewCell`. You need a custom option.

Comment: Try this tutorial. http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views

Comment: Thanks thus far. Anybody an idea why UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert will not be displayed?

Comment: You should not insert at the last of cell. Totally, it is not logic. you should using a button Edit to Add more cell. The simple way you should using a custom view controller to custom your tableview. Very easy

Answer (score 0):

You can use undocumented delegate methods for *UITableView* in iOS7

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForSwipeAccessoryButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return @"More";
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView swipeAccessoryButtonPushedForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
}
```

It seems that they are not private and can be submitted to appStore.

Comment: Very strange downvote on perfectly working solution!